# Powershell write value to serial port

Tags: powershell

How can I write the value 255 to the serial port in Powershell ?

```
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM6,4800,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.Write([char]255)
$port.Close()
```

The output of the previous script is 63 (viewed with a serial port monitor).

However `$port.Write([char]127)` gives 127 as result. If the value is higher than 127 the output is always 63.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: change the encoding of the serial port to 28591

Comment: Can you give me an example please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite your attempt to use `[char]`, **your argument is treated as `[string]`**, because PowerShell chooses the following overload of the `Write` method, given that you're only passing a *single* argument:

```bash
void Write(string text)
```

The [documentation for this particular overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_Write_System_String_) states (emphasis added):

> By default, SerialPort uses ASCIIEncoding to encode the characters. **ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or '?'**. To support additional characters in that range, set Encoding to UTF8Encoding, UTF32Encoding, or UnicodeEncoding.

---

**To send *byte* values,** you must use the following overload:

```bash
void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
```

That requires you to:

- use cast `[byte[]]` to cast your byte value(s)
- and specify values for `offset` - the starting byte position as well as `count`, the number of bytes to copy from the starting byte position.

In your case:

```bash
$port.Write([byte[]] (255), 0, 1)
```

<sup>Note: The `(...)` around `255` isn't required for a *single* value, but would be necessary to specify *multiple*, `,`-separated values.</sup>

---

Note:

- If you want to send entire *strings*, and those strings include characters *outside the ASCII range*, you'll need to set the port's character encoding first, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74091989/45375), which also shows an alternative solution based on obtaining a byte-array representation of a string based on the desired encoding (which then allows you to use the same method overload as above).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$port1 = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,4800,None,8,one
$port1.Open()
$data = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF32.GetBytes([char]255)
$port1.Write( $data )
$port1.ReadExisting()
$port1
$port1.Close()
```

Should work.