# Problems writing string with ASCII value > 127 to serial port with Powershell script

Tags: powershell, encoding, port

My problem is to retrieve real-time data from an inverter (Voltronic family).
The inverter has a server and, if correctly asked, can send back information according to a communication protocol.
The communication is done through the serial port.
In particular a string similar to "XXXX"+  + CR has to be sent and the relevant data are sent back.
In my case the only string I need to send is "QPIGS". In this case I would have back  many information that will allow me to produce a sort of control desk.
Since the string I need is always and only this, I made an off-line calculation of the `<crc>` that I need to complete the request.
The `<crc>` value is composed by two bytes, `"·©"`. The first is the "mid point", hex b7, and the second is the "copyright sign" hex a9.
So the complete string should be `"QPIGS·©"`. if I add the CR in powershell `` "`r" ``, the complete string should be `` "QPIGS·©`r" ``.

The script is very simple:

```
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,2400,None,8,one
$port.ReadTimeout = 1000
$port.open()
$str='QPIGS·©`r'
$port.WriteLine($str')
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300
while ($x = $port.ReadExisting())
{
    Write-Host $x
}

$port.Close()
```

But unfortunately it didn't work.
The inverter recognise the string but it doesn't match with what it was expecting and send back a NACK response. The exchange happens but is not succesfull.

In order to investigate more deeply I used a serial port serial sniffer to have evidence of what was really sent to the inverter and I found that what has been sent is the following

```
175 15/10/2022 17:06:29 IRP_MJ_WRITE DOWN  51 50 49 47 53 3f 3f 0a  QPIGS??. 8 8 COM1
```

instead of what I was expecting

```
175 15/10/2022 17:06:29 IRP_MJ_WRITE DOWN  51 50 49 47 53 b7 a9 0d  QPIGS·©. 8 8 COM1
```

It seems that the two `<crc>` bytes are ignored and substituted with two `?`, hex 3f.

I imagine a problem of encoding.......but I can't find a solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send ASCII values greater than 127 to serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503354/how-to-send-ascii-values-greater-than-127-to-serial-port)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell write value to serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611163/powershell-write-value-to-serial-port)

Comment: It would make sense to send these values as bytes and not characters: `$port.Write([byte[]] (0xB7, 0xA9), 0, 2)`

Comment: Hi CherryDT, thanks to your suggestion. the solution was to send all the string as byte $port.Write([byte[]] (0x51, 0x50, 0x49, 0x47, 0x53, 0xB7, 0xA9, 0x0d), 0, 8)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [CherryDT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1871033/cherrydt) for his comments and links to relevant related posts.</sup>

> the complete string should be `"QPIGS·©"` [ + `` "`r" `` for a CR]

- If you **send *strings* to a serial port**, its ***character encoding* matters**.
- The ***default* encoding is [*ASCII*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)**, which means that **only Unicode characters in the 7-bit ASCII subrange can be sent**, which *excludes* `·` (MIDDLE DOT, [`U+00B7`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b7)) and `©` (COPYRIGHT SIGN, [`U+00A9`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9)) - that is, any Unicode character whose code point is greater than `0x7f` (`127`) is "lossily" converted to a *verbatim* ASCII-range `?` character, `0x3f` (`63`).

You have two basic **options**:

- **Avoid *string* processing altogether and send an *array of bytes***: Convert the `QPIGS` substring to an array of (ASCII-range) byte values and append byte values `0xb7` and `0xa9`:

  - Because the .NET strings are *Unicode* strings (encodes as UTF-16LE code units), you can take advantage of the fact that the code-point range `0x0` - `0x7f` coincides with the ASCII code-point range, so you can simply cast ASCII-range characters to `[byte[]]` (via a `[char[]]` cast):

    ```bash
    # Results in the following byte array:
    #  [byte[]] (0x51, 0x50, 0x49, 0x47, 0x53, 0xb7, 0xa9, 0xd)
    [byte[]] $bytes = [char[]] 'QPIGS' + 0xb7, 0xa9, [char] "`r"

    $port.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Count)
    ```
- **Use the port's `.Encoding` property to specify a character encoding in which the *string* `` "QPIGS·©`r" `` results in the desired byte values**:

  - In this case you need the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding, where `·` is represented as byte value `0xb7`, and `©` as `0xa9`, and all ASCII-range characters are represented by their usual byte values:

    ```bash
    $port.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)

    $port.Write("QPIGS·©`r")
    ```